# What Encryption is this?

Tags: encryption, password-encryption

Can someone help me know what encryption type is this?

CpDUtTwxcAo=

At first I thought it was base64 but base64 ends with ==

Comment: No, Base64 can also end with `=` or any other character: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding Your string decodes to `<1p` in ASCII. Ow, and another thing, Base64 is no encryption, but an encoding.

Comment: Must be OTP... and the unencrypted message is anything you like it to be... <ironyoff />

Comment: @BartFriederichs It does not decode to `<1p`, it decoded to binary, some of the bytes are not printable characters.

Comment: @zaph oh, ok. I just threw it in an online decoder.

Comment: A particularly flexible converter with many input/output encodings: [online_tools/base64](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/base64.php?lang=en). Note that Base64 encoding is generally used to encode binary to an ASCII representation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is impossible to determine which algorithm produced this output, since ciphertexts and hash outputs are supposed to be indistinguishable from random noise and there are *infinitely* many of them. We're not here to play the [guessing game](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/), but you can guess yourself: [determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/3989/45523)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CpDUtTwxcAo=` is Base64 encoded data and decodes to binary, in hex: `0A 90 D4 B5 3C 31 70 0A`. Base64 is generally used to encode binary data to ASCII characters.

Note: Base64 is an encoding, not encryption.

See [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) for more information.